# Any way to monitor git branches and commits live?

Tags: git

Is there any tool out there that allows me to have a live view (updated at intervals or via git hooks?) of all remote branches of a repository?

It would be great to see:

- commit message / user
- merges
- branches

The purpose is to have an overview of the whole project, and see the progress happening in (near) real-time on each feature (where each feature is in it's own branch.)

Note: the repository is hosted on bitbucket

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the activity stream on each repository's overview page not show this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [slack](http://slack.com) with [bitbucket integration](https://slack.com/apps/A0F7VRDPE-bitbucket), here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Aside, it seems really redundant to append your name to the end of each commit. Is there any reason for this instead of just looking at the commit author or using `git blame`?

Comment: @CharlesDurham For the same reason it's not just a list of commit IDs. They're all things you want to know at a glance without having to drill into each commit. The branch is what is changing. The commit summary is what changed. The author is who to ask about it. I suspect it will even be their Slack username to make that conversation happen even faster.

Comment: I am looking for something more of a visualization of the branches in a tree-like structure to see branch-off points and merge points. It'd be a plus if the UI were interactive and you could hide/all commit messages, hashes, etc

Comment: This github project is on the right track to what I am looking for: https://github.com/kdheepak89/c3.py 
1. It is live
2. It shows the tree (this is where it lacks the branches, and more commit information which I would prefer to show by hovering or clicking on the commit)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this project: https://github.com/ivancea/git-monitor (I am the owner)

It lets you configure N repositories, and you will receive notifications via web.

It is still in development, but the basic features are already there